# wrong sql queries with laravel relation

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, relational-database

Here are my tables

```
Schema::create('badge_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreignId('badge_id')->references('id')->on('badges')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
```

```
Schema::create('badges', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->text('description')->nullable();
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->integer('condition');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
```

Here are relationships
In BagdeUser modal

```
public function badge()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Badge::class);

    }
```

In Badge modal

```
 public function badgeUser()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(BadgeUser::class , 'badge_id');

    }
```

In my resource

I have fetched all the data from the badge_user table and passed it in the resource

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'badges' => new BadgeResource($this->badge),
        ];
    }
```

BadeResource

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'description' => $this->description,
            'image' => new MediaResource($this->getMedia('badge')->first()),
            'condition' => $this->condition,
        ];
```

While fetching data o got this

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'badges.badge_user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `badges` where `badges`.`badge_user_id` = 1 and `badges`.`badge_user_id` is not null and `badges`.`deleted_at` is null)
```

Now I want the badges associate with the user

Comment: why are you using a model for a  pivot table ?

Comment: then how can I get the data, without the model??

Comment: the data in your pivot table is related to both user and media, you get it throught that using a many to many relation. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many all details you need to know are in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in your **badge_user** migration, you create foreign key **badge_id** which would mean that there is a relation **Badge User N:1 Badge**

But in your models you assign that BadgeUser has many Badges and Badge belongs to BadgeUser (which is **Badge User 1:N Badge**)

That is why laravel is looking for **badge_user_id** in query, because you defined the relationship the other way around.

Still tho you are probably doing M:N relations which you don't need to do manually.

You should use something like this (from Laravel docs)

```
return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
```